# Is there a way to specify both IPaddress and Subnet Id to webapp's access restrictions using ARM templates

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-webapps

I have a list of IP addresses and a specific subnet which are to be allowed access to webapp. I'm able to loop through the IP restrictions using `copy` function in ARM templates but I'm unable to add the subnet restriction in the same template. Is there a way I can get through this?

Comment: Can you please add your template?

Comment: have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/sites#IpSecurityRestriction?

Comment: Is it useful fro you?

Comment: Yes, I've went through the link and there is no way to include both subnet Id and IP addresses while using `copy` to add restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot of docs and blogs, I found no way to achieve it using the same ARM template. In my case, I want to add both IP addresses and a subnet while using a `copy` function(rather call it an ARM foreach loop). So, for adding multiple IP addresses(which are dynamically fetched within the ARM template from an other resource) and a subnet, I've got it resolved by executing the ARM first(this iterates and adds dynamically fetched IPs) and then a simple Az cmd as below which would add a security restriction to the same web app.

`Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -WebAppName $WebAppName -Name "subnet rule" -Priority 301 -Action Allow -SubnetName $subnetName -VirtualNetworkName $VnetName`

That way both are in place :D

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-appservice/ipsecurityrestriction?view=azure-node-latest) you can define the `ipAddress` property of `IpSecurityRestriction` as follows:

- CIDR notation such as ipv4/mask (leading bit match) e.g. XX.XXX.XXX.XX/32
- pure ipv4 address (in this case `SubnetMask` property is required )

According to what I understand you should be able to achieve your goal with this. But if you want a stricter answer, **please provide a sample input and a sample output**.

Comment: Yes, it has both the properties, but only one of them can be used at a time. If you try using both at once, it raises an error stating "Either one of them should be defined". This is specific to the case using `copy` function to add multiple  IP restrictions.

Comment: That is correct. Why would you need both in one rule? It is either a specific IP or a "list" of IPs. You should be able to define multiple `IpSecurityRestriction` items and thus including IP and subnet as separate rules.

Comment: I don't have a static set of IP addresses to be added and hence, I'm fetching it on the fly and iterating through them to add IPv4. But, in addition I also need to allow another subnet also.Hence, I had to go with the powershell way of appending the security restrictions apart from the ARM template restrictions(IPs dynamically fetched) made.